# Unable to export VM from Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

**TLDR;**
Incorrect function (0x80070001) means the Hard Disk is stuffed. If this is you, hope you had backups!

**The full story**
I'm trying to move a Virtual Machine from 1 disk to another on the host.
However, when I try to export the VM it runs for about 15 minutes with the progress in the status column slowly ticking along and then eventually it pops up the following error:

```
An error occurred while attempting to export the virtual machine.
Failed to copy file during export.
Failed to copy file from 'D:\VMs\SuperServer\Virtual Hard Disks\SuperServer.vhdx' 
to 'E:\VMs\SuperServer\Virtual Hard Disks\SuperServer.vhdx': 
Incorrect function. (0x80070001).
```

Exporting via powershell gives the same error in a slightly different format.

```
Export-VM : Failed to copy file during export.
Failed to copy file from 'D:\VMs\SuperServer\Virtual Hard Disks\SuperServer.vhdx' 
to 'E:\VMs\SuperServer\Virtual Hard Disks\SuperServer.vhdx'
: Incorrect function. (0x80070001).
At line:1 char:1
+ Export-VM -Name SuperServer -Path 'E:\VMs\'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Export-VM], VirtualizationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.ExportVM
```

No files are created, just an empty folder. There are other VMs on this disk in the same folder.
The vhdx file is over 100GB and the avhdx file is 25GB.
The source hard disk has 800GB free, and the target disk has 300GB free. Smaller I know, but its SSD.
The VM is in the "Off" State when I try to export it.
There are no errors in the event viewer when this happens.

**Edit 1:**
Possibly related to the problem is that the scheduled backup for all VMs is also failing. We're using the built in Windows Server Backup. The error that this is giving is:

```
Error in backup of D:\VMs\SuperServer\Virtual Hard Disks\SuperServer.vhdx during read: 
Error [0x80070001] Incorrect function.

Writer Id: {some hexadecimal string}
Component: some other hexadecimal string
Caption     : Offline\SuperServer
Logical Path: 
Error           : 8078010E
Error Message   : Copy of the files failed.

Detailed Error  : 80070001
Detailed Error Message : (null)
```

The backup destination is a Spanned volume of multiple disks which has a total of 4TB free. All the disks report as healthy.

**Edit 2:**
Trying to simply copy the files is also giving errors. I've tried Robocopy, but it fails on the 2 biggest files. I tried with and without the /J flag for unbuffered copy.

```
robocopy D:\VMs\SuperServer E:\VMs\SuperServer /E /ZB /DCOPY:T /COPYALL /R:1 /W:1 /V /TEE /LOG:Robocopy.log
```

The rest of the files copied fine but these 2 files were unsuccessful

```
87.5%      New File             109.3 g        SuperServer.vhdx
2020/10/28 13:22:43 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying File D:\VMs\SuperServer\Virtual Hard Disks\SuperServer.vhdx
Access is denied.
Waiting 1 seconds... Retrying...
87.5%      New File             109.3 g        SuperServer.vhdx
2020/10/28 13:49:45 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying File D:\VMs\SuperServer\Virtual Hard Disks\SuperServer.vhdx
Access is denied.
ERROR: RETRY LIMIT EXCEEDED.

7.6%      New File              23.9 g        SuperServer_Some_Hex_String.avhdx
2020/10/28 13:51:21 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying File D:\VMs\SuperServer\Virtual Hard Disks\SuperServer_Some_Hex_String.avhdx
Access is denied.
Waiting 1 seconds... Retrying...
7.6%      New File              23.9 g        SuperServer_Some_Hex_String.avhdx
2020/10/28 13:51:21 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying File D:\VMs\SuperServer\Virtual Hard Disks\SuperServer_Some_Hex_String.avhdx
Access is denied.
```

At the same time there was a number of these Warnings in the event viewer:

```
An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk3\DR3 during a paging operation.
```

and HardDisk3 is indeed D drive.

**Edit 3:**
I ran a `chkdsk /f` and it reported no errors. I was loath to run `chkdsk /R` because it has to demount the drive and it takes many hours. I've got other VMs on that disk, so to lose all of them for half a day was a pain. However, once running it, it started reporting bad clusters in exactly the files that I was unable to copy. In addition, this disk was so bad that it had run out of space to move the bad sectors.

```
The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters detected in file 88 of name \VMs\SUPERSERVER\VIRTUA~1\SUPERSERVER.vhdx.
```

And in case you are wondering, yes there was plenty of free space on the drive, but [bad sectors need a different kind of free space](https://superuser.com/a/266042/105881).

To make matters worse, after the chkdsk had finished, another of the VMs on the same drive was no longer able to be booted and had to be recovered from a backup.

Comment: Do you have the rights to write in the folder on the E drive?

Comment: As @LeRouteur said, do you see files created on the destination during the move? If not it is likely a permission issue.

Otherwise, in VM settings do you see any issues or missing disks, checkpoints? 
You could also try moving with powershell through Export-VM :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/export-and-import-virtual-machines

Comment: @LeRouteur I believe that I do have write permission. SYSTEM and the local administrators group (of which I am a member) both have Full Control.

Comment: @Martinos it creates an empty folder with the name of the VM on the destination drive, but no files inside it. There are some errors with scheduled backups so I'll add those details to the post.

Comment: Try to run a check disk on your D drive. According to your second edit, paging error could be the problem (maybe a bad sector or something like that).

Comment: @LeRouteur running `chkdsk /R` now. Unfortunately it had to dismount and turn off 4 other VM's on the same disk. Even worse its been running for 3 hrs and estimated finish time is another 5 hrs. I had run `chkdsk /F` before and it found nothing, but `/R` has found some bad clusters. Also unfortunately it says `The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters detected in file 88 of name \VMs\SUPERSERVER\VIRTUA~1\SUPERSERVER.vhdx.`

Comment: Hmmm looks like an hardware problem. Do you have any spare disk?

Comment: @LeRouteur I do - but the problem is I cannot move the VM to it.

Comment: By using a spare disk I mean replacing the E drive and test again.

Comment: @LeRouteur ahah I see sorry :) Yes I have another disk, lets call it F drive, and unfortunately it is the same issue. However, I have made some progress - I can export a checkpoint! If I create a new checkpoint I can't export that, but an older checkpoint before the hard disk went bad can be exported to E or F!

Comment: Happy you figured out how to resolve your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backup and the export have one thing in common: the source. There is probably something wrong with your VHD or other Hyper-V files.

This guy solved it by copying the data inside the VM using Robocopy, but that may not work for you: https://evotec.xyz/hyper-v-incorrect-function-when-trying-to-move-files/

---

Your updated post shows that your drive is failing. If `chkdsk /r` can't fix it, you'll need to use a different recovery method. Data loss is a near certainty here. You need to decide if saving this machine is worth it, or if you want to rebuild. No matter what, you need to stop using this disk, even if `chkdsk /r` can fix it.

Comment: Yep that D: hard drive is stuffed. I couldn't copy the files for the VM any which way - the vhdx file was too damaged. This was surprising because the VM still ran, albeit slowly. BUT, I did manage to export a checkpoint from the VM to another disk and have restored from there.

Answer (score 1):

A week after having to recover the VM from backups, the physical hard disk was recovered!

This was done by removing it from the server and then it was reattached and reimported and started working again. So worth a try if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the VM to a folder on the source disk. If this works then the problem is with the destination.

Also, if this works then try to copy the exported VM to the destination and import it from there and see if you get the same errors.

Comment: Same error when exporting to a different folder on the source drive :(

Comment: OK. It sounds like there's a problem with the VM files then. Does the VM run?

Comment: Yes it runs - but very slowly. Hence why I want to move it